# SQL syntax error: missing operator

Tags: sql, syntax, operators

I have a missing operator  error for this query. Can't seem to figure out what the missing operator is!

```
    SELECT Ordre.Ordre, Sum(Ordre.Duree), Ordre.Designation AS SommeDeDuree 
    FROM Ordre 
    WHERE (((Ordre.Date) > #21/10/2011# And (Ordre.Date) < #25/10/2011#) 
      And ((Ordre.CentreCout) = '5240') And ((Ordre.Ordre) <> 11131906 
      And (Ordre.Ordre) <> 12155996 And (Ordre.Ordre) <> 11147473 
      And (Ordre.Ordre) <> 11147548 And (Ordre.Ordre) <> 11131906)  
    GROUP BY Ordre.Ordre;
```

Comment: You have one more open parenthesis than you do closing.

Comment: Done. Just glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one more open parenthesis than you do closing.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Ordre.Ordre, Sum(Ordre.Duree), Ordre.Designation AS SommeDeDuree 
FROM Ordre 
WHERE (Ordre.Date > '21/10/2011') 
AND (Ordre.Date < '25/10/2011') 
And (Ordre.CentreCout = '5240') 
And (Ordre.Ordre <> 11131906) 
And (Ordre.Ordre <> 12155996) 
And (Ordre.Ordre <> 11147473) 
And (Ordre.Ordre <> 11147548)
And (Ordre.Ordre <> 11131906)
GROUP BY Ordre.Ordre;
```